# Getting all Named Parameters from Powershell including empty and set ones

Tags: powershell, parameters

I'm trying to find a way to get all parameter information from a powershell script. Ex script:

```
function test()
{
    Param(
        [string]$foo,
        [string]$bar,
        [string]$baz = "baz"
    )

    foreach ($key in $MyInvocation.BoundParameters.keys)
    {
        write-host "Parameter: $($key) -> $($MyInvocation.BoundParameters[$key])"
    }
}
test -foo "foo!"
```

I'd like to get the values of `$bar` and `$baz` in a dynamic way without knowing the names of the parameters ahead of time.

I've looked through `$MyInvocation` properties and methods but I don't see anything besides parameters that are set/passed.

**Update 1:**

I'm close to getting it with:

```
function test()
{
    Param(
        [string]$foo,
        [string]$bar,
        [string]$baz = "baz"
    )
    foreach($var in (get-variable -scope private))
    {
        write-host "$($var.name) -> $($var.value)"
    }
}
test -foo "foo!"
```

If i could filter out the script parameters vs the default parameters I would be good to go.

**Update 2:**
The final working solution looks like this:

```
function test {
    param (
          [string] $Bar = 'test'
        , [string] $Baz
        , [string] $Asdf
    )
    $ParameterList = (Get-Command -Name $MyInvocation.InvocationName).Parameters;
    foreach ($key in $ParameterList.keys)
    {
        $var = Get-Variable -Name $key -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
        if($var)
        {
            write-host "$($var.name) > $($var.value)"
        }
    }
}

test -asdf blah;
```

Comment: Your answer seems to work and... is different than the accepted answer. Is there a reason you didn't add it as an answer and accept it if it's the best answer? (And I would argue it may be, since there's no `[CmdletBinding()]` requirement.)

Comment: Aside: `Get-Variable` returns an object with `Name` and `Value` properties. In some use cases you may know the name in advance and just need to check if the value was supplied (e.g. optional ScriptBlock parameter, running in strict mode with `Set-StrictMode -Version 3`). `Get-Variable` has a switch `-ValueOnly` for returning just the value and `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` takes care of returning `$null` instead of throwing an exception if the parameter was not supplied.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Check this solution out. This uses the `CmdletBinding()` attribute, which provides some additional metadata through the use of the `$PSCmdlet` built-in variable. You can:

1. Dynamically retrieve the command's name, using `$PSCmdlet`
2. Get a list of the parameter for the command, using `Get-Command`
3. Examine the value of each parameter, using the `Get-Variable` cmdlet

Code:

```
function test {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
          [string] $Bar = 'test'
        , [string] $Baz
        , [string] $Asdf
    )
    # Get the command name
    $CommandName = $PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.InvocationName;
    # Get the list of parameters for the command
    $ParameterList = (Get-Command -Name $CommandName).Parameters;

    # Grab each parameter value, using Get-Variable
    foreach ($Parameter in $ParameterList) {
        Get-Variable -Name $Parameter.Values.Name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
        #Get-Variable -Name $ParameterList;
    }
}

test -asdf blah;
```

### Output

The output from the command looks like this:

```
Name                           Value                                           
----                           -----                                           
Bar                            test                                            
Baz                                                                            
Asdf                           blah
```

Comment: Yes! This kind of approach is exactly what I was looking for. I ended up having to touch up the script a bit because I kept getting nulls, but this is definitely the way to go. Thanks!

Comment: @EricLongstreet Glad to hear that worked for you. :)

Comment: I think you can skip the `$PSCmdlet` and `Get-Command` and just use `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Parameters`, and that you can just loop over `Parameters.Keys` to get the parameter names.

Comment: Also worth noting that `$PSCmdlet` only works if you have an explicit `[CmdletBinding()]`, whereas `$MyInvocation.MyCommand` works for all functions.

Comment: Some technical notes for if you want to adapt this sample code for other uses: 1. `$Parameter.Values.Name` is a list of names, not a single name, so you may want to iterate through this list if you're passing it to something other than `Get-Variable` (which accepts lists without issue). 2. `Get-Variable` produces object output which is nice for table display, but requires extra effort to pass as a parameter. Accessing through the `Variable:` drive instead may help, e.g. `Get-Content "Variable:$name"`.

Comment: @Tydaeus - self-correction: Use the `Value` property of the Get-Variable output, or from `Get-Item "Variable:$name"`. `Get-Content "Variable:$name"` doesn't work properly with arrays.

Answer (score 17):

To read the value dynamically use the `get-variable` function / cmdlet

```
write-host (get-variable "foo")
```

To print out all of the parameters do the following

```
foreach ($key in $MyInvocation.BoundParameters.keys)
{
    $value = (get-variable $key).Value 
    write-host "$key -> $value"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, wasn't aware of that commandlet.
However, i'm looking to get the values dynamically without knowing the names of the variables.

Comment: @EricLongstreet my updated sample doesn't use any fixed names.  It just goes straight through the bound parameter list

Comment: Sorry missed that, however it looks like $MyInvocation.BoundParameters.keys doesn't contain $bar and $baz, only actual bounded parameters. I'm really interested in getting $baz who might have a default value set already and is never passed

Comment: This actually worked for me in case of calling a .ps1 file using `& .\MyScript.ps1 -param1 value 1`.  Using `$MyInvocation.InvocationName` would return `&`

Comment: confirmed: does not include parameters not explicitly passed, should not be upvoted. see this instead (same thread answer by Janos):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47290923/1279373

Answer (score 8):

Hopefully, some may find this one-liner useful:

```
function test()
{
    Param(
        [string]$foo,
        [string]$bar,
        [string]$baz = "baz"
    )

    $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Parameters | Format-Table -AutoSize @{ Label = "Key"; Expression={$_.Key}; }, @{ Label = "Value"; Expression={(Get-Variable -Name $_.Key -EA SilentlyContinue).Value}; }
}
test -foo "foo!"
```

Result

```
Keys Value
---- -----
foo  foo! 
bar       
baz  baz
```

Comment: upvoted bc this works, including values not explicitly passed and assigned by default. However, it also includes many other variables which i suppose are powershell global/overhead of some kind:
```Verbose Debug ErrorAction WarningAction InformationAction ErrorVariable WarningVariable InformationVariable OutVariable OutBuffer PipelineVariable```

Answer (score 7):

I found this most useful for PS4 (Windows 2012 R2) - it includes default values / optional parameters:

```
$cmdName = $MyInvocation.InvocationName
$paramList = (Get-Command -Name $cmdName).Parameters
foreach ( $key in $paramList.Keys ) {
    $value = (Get-Variable $key -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Value
    if ( $value -or $value -eq 0 ) {
        Write-Host "$key -> $value"
    }
}
```

Comment: this is perfect! it includes params not explicitly passed and it omitted the system/global variables like the following ```Verbose Debug ErrorAction WarningAction InformationAction ErrorVariable WarningVariable InformationVariable OutVariable OutBuffer PipelineVariable```

Answer (score 5):

For those of you who do not want to use cmdletbinding() here's a variation on the one liner I found above:

```
(Get-Command -Name $PSCommandPath).Parameters | Format-Table -AutoSize @{ Label = "Key"; Expression={$_.Key}; }, @{ Label = "Value"; Expression={(Get-Variable -Name $_.Key -EA SilentlyContinue).Value}; }
```

$PSCommandPath is always available

Comment: Wow thanks...saved my day. I had issues not getting any decent return from the function rated best above....switched over to "Invoke-Expression" to get a return value but that brought different issues for me...so I reverted to "&" for calling one ps1 script from another one and took your solution.

Answer (score 2):

A streamlined solution that:

- builds on your own approach now shown at the bottom of the question,
- while also including an additional piece of information, namely *whether each parameter was bound* on invocation, i.e. whether an argument was passed or not, based on its presence in the [automatic `$PSBoundParameter` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables), which is a dictionary containing the bound parameters and their values (arguments).

  - Note: `$PSBoundParameters` does *not* include parameters bound by a *default value*, only those parameters to which an argument was *explicitly* passed; for your use case, that is arguably desirable in order to distinguish between a default value and an explicit one, but in scenarios where arguments should be *passed through* it may be desirable to have default-value parameters included - see  [GitHub issue #3285](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3285).

```
function test {
  param (
    [string]$foo,
    [string]$bar,
    [string]$baz = "baz"
  )
  foreach ($paramName in $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Parameters.Keys) {
    $bound = $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey($paramName)
    [pscustomobject] @{
      ParameterName = $paramName
      ParameterValue = if ($bound) { $PSBoundParameters[$paramName] }
                       else { Get-Variable -Scope Local -ErrorAction Ignore -ValueOnly $paramName }
      Bound = $bound
    }
  }
}

test -foo "foo!"
```

The above  yields the following:

```
ParameterName ParameterValue Bound
------------- -------------- -----
foo           foo!            True
bar                          False
baz           baz            False
```

Note: This solution also handles [*dynamic* parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters#dynamic-parameters) correctly:

- Such parameters are reflected in `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Parameters` if they situationally apply, but - unlike regular *static* parameters - are *never* reflected in scope-local *variables*. If they apply and are also *bound*, they and their values are reflected in `$PSBoundParameters`.
- Thus - given that an applicable dynamic parameter may not be bound - the `Get-Variable` call to look for scope-local variables representing *static* parameters:

  - Must explicitly be limited to the current scope with `-Scope Local` so as not to accidentally pick up unrelated variables of the same name from ancestral scopes for unbound dynamic parameters.
  - Must ignore errors from the potentially resulting failure to find a variable in the current scope, using `-ErrorAction Ignore`.

Answer (score 1):

I played with the 2 solutions i liked in this thread, they both work. 
however I needed to produce an error out on missing parameter for a build script

```
   $cmdName = $MyInvocation.InvocationName 
   $paramList = (Get-Command -Name $cmdName).Parameters
     foreach ( $key in $paramList.Keys ) {
     $value = (Get-Variable $key -ErrorAction Stop)
     #Write-Host $value.Value #remove comment for error checking
        if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($value.Value)){ 
        $(throw ("$key is a mandatory value please declare with -$key <Required value> " ))
        }
       }
```

Comment: Wouldn't you handle the missing parameter as an error by defining it using [Parameter( Mandatory )] and add [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]?

Answer (score 1):

What if I don't know what arguments or how many will be passed? For example, the function could be called with:

```
test -foo "value1" -bar "value2" -baz "value3"
```

and someone else might call it with:

```
test -variable1 "somevalue" -variable2 "somevalue2" -variable3 "somevalue3" -variable4 "value4"
```

I looked at `$MyInvocation` and the arguments come across as UnboundArguments, so theoretically I could "pair up" argument 0 with argument 1, 2 with 3, etc and error out if there's an odd number of UnboundArguments.

Comment: My "Update 2" example should work for this case as well, GL.

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled upon this trying to do something similar and figured out my preferred option.

```
Function ParamTest {
    Param (
        $t1 = '1234',
        $t2,
        [switch]$3
    )
    
    $MyInvocation |Add-Member -Name:'Param' -MemberType:'NoteProperty' -Value:(
        (Get-Variable -Scope:'Local' -Include:@($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Parameters.keys)|
            ForEach-Object -begin:{$h=@{}} -process:{$h.add($_.Name,$_.Value)} -end:{$h}
    ))

    $MyInvocation.Param
}
```

Result

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
t1                             1234                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
3                              False                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
t2
```

PSVersionTable

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.1320                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.1320                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a compact string of parameter key/value pairs that I can write out when catching error. Use content of the other answers, I came up with this:

```
$parameters = (Get-Variable -Scope:'Local' -Include:@($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Parameters.keys) |
        Select-Object Name, Value | ForEach-Object { "$($_.Name) : $($_.Value)" }) -join ' | '
```

Sample output:

```
ComputerName : SomePC | Directory : C:\Tools\LogExpert | UserName : Hans Wurst | YesOrNo : False
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all other posters with great & helpful answers above!
I'm cobbling together some of the above posts to try to meet my requirements.
I'd like to show Params in a **Powershell-language-compatible** format, so that one could easily see & display these params, and then also copy+pasta back into either a script as Param() Defaults (**ParamsFormat1**) or into a commandline/function call (**CommandFormat2**).  I struggled with this for a while, so I hope this saves someone some time.

Collection of various Scripts from above:

```
# Note: there are some subtle differences between these versions below
# Specifically in the first line for *which* object you're checking for Parameters, and subsequently what type of Parameters you're looking at.


# PSCmdlet version REQUIRES [CmdletBinding()] on your function!!!
# $($(Get-Command -Name $($PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.InvocationName)).Parameters) | `
#   %{ Get-Variable -Name $_.Values.Name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue; } 

# -Scope:'Local' FILTERS out any global params
# (Get-Variable -Scope:'Local' -Include:@($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Parameters.keys)) | ft

# PSCommandPath supposedly available/usable "in all situations" - so this may be the most useful of all of them, BUT it shows global params [Debug, ErrorAction, etc...]
# (Get-Command -Name $PSCommandPath).Parameters  | `
#    %{ Get-Variable -Name $_.Values.Name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue; }
```

**ParamsFormat1 / HYBRID VERSION:** To output "Default Params" as you would see them in a function definition. Combines the -Scope:"Local" and "always available" versions to get BOTH param TYPES as well as Name, Value

```
Write-Host "Params("
# TBD Figure out how to expand @{} of System.Collections.Hashtable

# HYBRID VERSION: Combine the -Scope:"Local" and "always available" versions to get BOTH param TYPES as well as Name, Value

# If you remove LocalList Filter here, it will also show "Global" function properties like Debug, ErrorAction, etc...
$LocalList = $(Get-Variable -Scope:'Local' -Include:@($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Parameters.keys) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name) -join "|"
# VERSION: Wrapper script with DEFAULTS : normally DOES include Global vars [Debug, ErrorAction, etc]. but DOES preserve param order as-written.
((Get-Command -Name $PSCommandPath).Parameters | `
    Select -ExpandProperty Values | `
    Where-Object { $_.Name -Match $LocalList } | `
    Format-Table -HideTableHeaders -AutoSize `
    @{ Label="Type"; Expression={"[$($_.ParameterType )]"}; }, `
    @{ Label="Name"; Expression={"`t`$$($_.Name)"}; }, `
    @{ Label="Equals"; Expression={"="}; }, `
    @{ Label="Value"; Expression={ If( $_.ParameterType -Match "String" ) { "`"$((Get-Variable -Name $_.Name -EA SilentlyContinue).Value)`"" } Else{ $((Get-Variable -Name $_.Name -EA SilentlyContinue).Value)}; }; }, `
    @{ Label="RowEndComma"; Expression={ "," }; }
    #@{ Label="Value"; Expression={ $((Get-Variable -Name $_.Name -EA SilentlyContinue).Value) }; } # (OPTIONAL) Values only, no wrapping quotes
)
Write-Host ")";
```

**CommandFormat2 / SIMPLER VERSION:** Call with CommandLine Args (TYPES not needed). This filters out Global vars, does NOT preserve param ordering. (sorted alphabetically?)

```
# VERSION: Call with CommandLine Args (TYPES not available - TBD needs more work to display String, Array, and Hashmap/PsCustomObject ["", @() and {}] types better): filters out Global vars, does NOT preserve param ordering.
# If needed, cut+paste OPTIONAL lines down above Format-Table line.
# Where-Object { $_.Value } | `     # (Optional) remove any Null items.  
# Sort-Object -Property Name | `    # (Optional) sort output
    (Get-Variable -Scope:'Local' -Include:@($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Parameters.keys) | `    
        Format-Table -HideTableHeaders -AutoSize `
        @{ Label="Name"; Expression={"`t-$($_.Name)"}; }, `
        @{ Label="Equals"; Expression ={":"}; }, `
        @{ Label="Value"; Expression={ If( $_.ParameterType -NotMatch "String" ) { $_.Value; } Else {"`"$($_.Value)`"";} }; Alignment="left"; }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking to find the default value of a command's parameter while in a **DynamicParam** block, I was able to leverage help documentation to achieve this.

Default values are not assigned to parameters until after dynamic parameters are evaluated, which means `$MyInvocation` isn't going to contain defaults when you observe it within a DynamicParam block, and parameters aren't even defined yet so you cannot use `Get-Variable` either.

```
(Get-Help -Name $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name -Full).parameters.parameter[0].defaultValue
```

If you ever re-order your parameter listing, or change `Position` properties, change the array value accordingly.  But, at least this keeps you from having to update hard-coded default values in multiple places.

If someone has a better way to find default parameter values inside a DynamicParam block of the same command without using help text, that would be great.